# JSCH + Expect4J, need additional login step before standard .expect and .send

Tags: java, sockets, ssh, jsch

I've writen a program that will login via SSH.  This server takes an additional step in that you need to provide it an area code and three digits of a telephone number when it prompts "Destination: ".  So, what I'm trying to do is have my terminal wait for the Destination: prompt, give it my six digits, then look at the resulting prompts to see where it went before executing my expect code.  There are five possible terminal types after the Destination: prompt, meaning I need to test the returning stream after giving it my six telephone number digits using regex.

Where I'm getting stuck is figuring out the best way to get the Destination: prompt, send it my digits, get the resulting code to execute my regex and if then statements, and then passing it onto one of several classes I'll be making to execute using expect4j from that point on.  Should I use an exec shell before moving over to expect, and if so, how do I get my input from it to run regex?  Should I send an expect.expect ("Destination: "); followed by an expect.send ("123456");, then get the input to run regex, and if so, how do I get the input from it? (my example code uses a buffer, which gets it's info from the execute method somehow, I don't really understand how it work completely,) or, my last option, should I build two instances of my example code, one that makes the session and ssh channel, sends my telephone digits, gets the input, runs regex, THEN send it to another expect4j class with new variables to run the remaining expect and sends?

**IN SHORT:** As far as I can tell those are my three options: run an exec shell, run a single expect.expect and expect.send before going into the more complicated list building and such, or running two lists with expect methods, one after the other.  Not sure which way to go, and how to get my input back to run the regex.

I've managed to get it to login to one of my five terminal options, examine, and disconnect, and most recently I've built code to login, supply the digits, and read the resulting code with regex to indicate which of my five types it is.  I just can't get them to work together.

My code is built off the example found at http://nikunjp.wordpress.com/2011/07/30/remote-ssh-using-jsch-with-expect4j/

```
    package switchoverlay;

    import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelShell;
    import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
    import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
    import expect4j.Closure;
    import expect4j.Expect4j;
    import expect4j.ExpectState;
    import expect4j.matches.Match;
    import expect4j.matches.RegExpMatch;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Hashtable;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.regex.Matcher;
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;
    import org.apache.oro.text.regex.MalformedPatternException;



    public class SSHLogin {

            static final String controlB = "\u0002";
            static final String controlC = "\u0003"; 
            static final String controlV = "\u0016";
            static final String cr = "\u0013";
            static final String lf = "\u0010";
            static final String sp = "\u0032";

            String npa = OverlayGUI.tn.substring(1, 4); //Get first three digits from tn
            String nxx = OverlayGUI.tn.substring(5, 8); //Get first three digits from tn
            String xxxx = OverlayGUI.tn.substring(9, 13); //Get last four digits from tn

            private static final int COMMAND_EXECUTION_SUCCESS_OPCODE = -2;
            private static String ENTER_CHARACTER = "\r";  //NOT GOOD FOR A GTD5!
            private static final int SSH_PORT = 22;
            private List<String> loginLstCmds = new ArrayList<String>();
            private static String[] switchPromptRegEx = new String[]
            {"\r\nDestination: ", //npanxx
            "via.{12}\r\n"}; //controlB

            private Expect4j expect = null;
            private StringBuilder loginBuffer = new StringBuilder();
            private String userName;
            private String password;
            private String host;

            /**
            *
            * @param host
            * @param userName
            * @param password
            */
            public SSHLogin(String host, String userName, String password) {
                    this.host = host;
                    this.userName = userName;
                    this.password = password;
            }
            /**
            *
            * @param LoginCmdsToExecute
            */
            public String execute(List<String> LoginCmdsToExecute) {
                    this.loginLstCmds = LoginCmdsToExecute;

                    Closure closure = new Closure() {
                            public void run(ExpectState expectState) throws Exception {
                                    loginBuffer.append(expectState.getBuffer());
                            }
                    };

                    List<Match> lstPattern =  new ArrayList<Match>();
                    for (String regexElement : switchPromptRegEx) {
                            try {
                                    Match mat = new RegExpMatch(regexElement, closure);
                                    lstPattern.add(mat);
                            } catch (MalformedPatternException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch(Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                    }

                    try {                
                            expect = SSH();
                            boolean isSuccess = true;                

                            for(String strCmd : loginLstCmds) {
                                    isSuccess = isSuccess(lstPattern,strCmd);
                                    if (!isSuccess) {
                                            isSuccess = isSuccess(lstPattern,strCmd);
                                    }
                            }

                            checkResult(expect.expect(lstPattern));
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                            testType();
                    }
                    return loginBuffer.toString();
            }
            /**
            *
            * @param objPattern
            * @param strCommandPattern
            * @return
            */
            private boolean isSuccess(List<Match> objPattern,String strCommandPattern) {
                    try {
                            boolean isFailed = checkResult(expect.expect(objPattern));

                            if (!isFailed) {

                                    expect.send(strCommandPattern);
                                    Thread.sleep( 8000);
                                    //expect.send(ENTER_CHARACTER);  //NOT GOOD FOR A GTD5!
                                    return true;
                            }
                            return false;
                    } catch (MalformedPatternException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                            return false;
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                            return false;
                    }
            }
            /**
            *
            * @param hostname
            * @param username
            * @param password
            * @param port
            * @return
            * @throws Exception
            */
            private Expect4j SSH() throws Exception {
                    JSch jsch = new JSch();
                    Session session = jsch.getSession(userName, host, SSH_PORT);
                    if (password != null) {
                            session.setPassword(password);
                    }
                    Hashtable<String,String> config = new Hashtable<String,String>();
                    config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
                    session.setConfig(config);
                    session.connect(120000);
                    ChannelShell channel = (ChannelShell) session.openChannel("shell");
                    channel.connect();                   
                    Expect4j expect = new Expect4j(channel.getInputStream(), channel.getOutputStream());          

                    return expect;              
            }
            /**
            *
            * @param intRetVal
            * @return
            */
            private boolean checkResult(int intRetVal) {
                    if (intRetVal == COMMAND_EXECUTION_SUCCESS_OPCODE) {
                            return true;
                    }
                    return false;
            }
            /**
            *
            */
            private void testType() {
            String lBString = loginBuffer.toString();
            System.out.println(lBString);


            Pattern gtd5 = Pattern.compile(".*GTD5.*");         
            Matcher gtd5Matcher = gtd5.matcher(lBString);
            if (gtd5Matcher.find()) {
                System.out.println("Your switch type is GTD5");
            }

            Pattern dms10 = Pattern.compile(".*DMS10^0.*");         
            Matcher dms10Matcher = dms10.matcher(lBString);
            if (dms10Matcher.find()) {
                System.out.println("Your switch type is DMS10");
            }

            Pattern dms100 = Pattern.compile(".*DMS100.*");         
            Matcher dms100Matcher = dms100.matcher(lBString);
            if (dms100Matcher.find()) {
                System.out.println("Your switch type is DMS100");
            }

            Pattern ess = Pattern.compile(".*5es.*");         
            Matcher essMatcher = ess.matcher(lBString);
            if (essMatcher.find()) {
                System.out.println("Your switch type is 5ESS");
            }

            Pattern dco = Pattern.compile(".*DCO.*");         
            Matcher dcoMatcher = dco.matcher(lBString);
            if (dcoMatcher.find()) {
                System.out.println("Your switch type is DCO");
            }


    //else { System.out.println("Switch type Error."); }

    //SSHGTD5ExamClient runSsh = new SSHGTD5ExamClient();  //pass on to expect4j based on regex for remaining expect and sends?

                                    //if (expect!=null) {  //old code for shutting down expect4j
                            //expect.close();



                    }


    }
```